# Finding all possible combinations with 1 element in each row of a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, combinations

Recently I have been trying to do a problem that requires me to find all the different combinations with selecting only 1 element from each row. For example, I'm inputting n rows with 2 strings per row. However, I only want to find all the different combinations where I choose 1 string from each row.

Example:

Input:

```
3
alex bob
straw mat
eat drink
```

Example combination:
alex straw drink

This results in 2^n combinations, which in this case would be 2^3 = 8 combinations. However, if I was to use n for loops to find the combinations
e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int n;
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    cin >> n; //rows of words
    string words[n][2]; //the words with 2 words per row

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cin >> words[i][j]; //input of words
        }
    }
    //finding all possible combinations
    for (int i =0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            for (int x=0; x<2; x++){
                //and so on per n
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this would take n for loops to find out all the combinations of the array with only taking one item from each row. What would be the best and simplest approach to finding all different combinations with size n as I would take 1 string out of the two in each row? Thanks.

Comment: Are there always exactly two elements per row, or shall the algorithm also work for more than 2 elements per row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution for a setting where you have always 2 elements per row would be to use datatype integer and interpret each bit as a decision for the first or the second column in the respective row; then simply count from 0 to 2^n - 1 in order to get all combinations.
Applied to your example this would look as follows:

```
int bits meaning
0   000  alex,straw,eat
1   001  alex,straw,drink
2   010  alex,mat,eat
3   011  alex,mat,dring
4   100  bob,straw,eat
5   101  bob,straw,drink
6   110  bob,mat,eat
7   111  bob,mat,drink
```

For any of the given integer values 0..7, use bit shift operators or &-bitmask to map each bit to a column index:

```cpp
void getCombinationRepresentedByIntValue(vector<string>& combination, int value) {  
  int mask = 1;
  for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
     if (value & mask)
       combination.push_back(words[i][1]);
     else
       combination.push_back(words[i][0]);
     mask = mask << 1;
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, bit shift seems to work the best, implementing that right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can do recursion.

Assuming C++11, something like this maybe (didn't try to compile this though):

```
// finding all possible combinations
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> combinations;

const auto processLine = [&](const std::vector<std::string>& currentCombination, int line) {    

    std::vector<std::string> combination0 = currentCombination;
    std::vector<std::string> combination1 = currentCombination;
    combination0.push_back(words[line][0]);
    combination1.push_back(words[line][1]);

    if (line + 1 < n) {
        // process next line
        processLine(combination0, line + 1);
        processLine(combination1, line + 1);
    }
    else {
        // last line - keep the result
        combinations.push_back(combination0);
        combinations.push_back(combination1);
    }
};

std::vector<std::string> empty;
processLine(empty, 0);

// print results
for (const auto& combination : combinations) {
    for (const auto& word : combination) {
        std::cout << word << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to answer your question :

```
    int ct[n]; // count of the number of pass 
    int current = 0; // index of the current word (n)

    /* while not all combinaison have been exploited */
    while (current >= 0)
    {
        cout << words[current][ct[current]];  /* <<<<< can be used another way*/
        /* down to the next word */
        current ++; // to get the next word
        if (current >=n) { // at the end of the list
            cout << " ";
            current--; // restore last
            ct[current]++; // increment number of time we passed
            /* find the previous not completely exploited */
            while (current >= 0 && ct[current]> 1) /* <<< change 1 to any number of words per line */
            {
                ct[current] = 0;
                current--;
                if (current >= 0) ct[current]++;
            }
            if (current > 0 ) current = 0;
        }
    }
```

With your example :

Input :

3
alex bob
straw mat
eat drink

output : 
alexstraweat
alexstrawdrink
alexmateat
alexmatdrink
bobstraweat
bobstrawdrink
bobmateat
bobmatdrink

hope it helps !